# How to start my else if for loop start with 01 - 09?

Tags: c++

How do I make my code specifically on else if to print out this if my input is 45?

01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08.09.10

11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20

21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30

31.32.33.34.35.36.37.38.39.40

41.42.43.44.45

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string dot = "";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x<=10){
        for (int n=1; n<=x; n++){
            cout << dot << n ;
            dot =".";
        }
    }
    else if(x>10&&x<=100) {
        for (int i = 1; i <=x; ++i){
            for (int j = 1; j <=10; ++j){
            cout << dot << x;
            dot=".";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "OUT OF RANGE";
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire program can be simplified using [setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [setfill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) to do the hard work for you of inserting leading zero chars where needed.  `#include <iomanip>` to have access to these stream modification functions.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << i;
        char delimiter = ((i % 10) && (i != x)) ? '.' : '\n';
        cout << delimiter;
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cin >> x;

    if (x > 100)
    {
        cout << "Out of range." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << i << ((i % 10) ? "." : "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `((i % 10) ? "." : "\n")`, you likely want `(  ((i % 10) && (i != x)  ) ? "." : "\n")` so the `.` doesn't get printed after the last integer.